# How to apply background color to only selected option in select tag

Tags: html, css

I can't set background-color of a selected option in a drop-down list. My working is:

```html
<select name="Occupancy Status" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option style="background-color:#333333" selected>Select your Occupany Status</option>
  <option>bla bla</option>
  <option>bla bla</option>
  <option>bla bla</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to achieve desired output? Thank you.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element

Comment: I don't see any customly styled option in any of the dropdowns, can you post a picture of that in your question?

Comment: @GeekyQuentin when the page loads, selected option in all dropdowns are set to #333333. I've highlighted one in this uploaded image. (https://ibb.co/XbxwgTc)

Comment: @atch The link you've provided is not working.

Comment: Yes, the link is not working

Comment: @Shrey which one?

Comment: (https://ibb.co/XbxwgTc) is not working. connection reset in chrome

Comment: @Shrey very strange. It is working fine here. Please try this one and let me know. Thanks (https://pasteboard.co/ImUePAEpC7gR.png)

Comment: @GeekyQuentin Please try (https://pasteboard.co/ImUePAEpC7gR.png) and let me know if its opening. Thanks

Comment: Yes it is working now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? It isn't polished at all just wanted to see if this is the basic behavior that you're describing that you can't figure out.

```css
.form {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.field-select {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  color: #fff;
}

.field-select > option {
  color: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="field">
    <label>What is your house type? <span>(Required)</span></label>
    <div>
      <select class="field-select" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="" selected="selected" class="field-placeholder">Select</option>
        <option value="Detached House">Detached House</option>
        <option value="Semi-Detached House">Semi-Detached House</option>
        <option value="Mid-Terrace House">Mid-Terrace House</option>
        <option value="End-Terrace House">End-Terrace House</option>
        <option value="Detached Bungalow">Detached Bungalow</option>
        <option value="Semi-Detached Bungalow">Semi-Detached Bungalow</option>
        <option value="Flat">Flat</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hit "Run code snippet" above, or check out [on my CodePen](https://codepen.io/stephenirving/pen/ExEXXbv).

Answer (score 0):

The `:checked` pseudo-class in CSS initially applies to such elements that have the HTML4 `selected` and `checked` attributes. This change the style of **selected** option from dropdown list. Also if you want to default the styling to unselected options you can just use `:not()` property.

---

```
option:not(:checked) {
  /*Your Styling Here*/
}
```

---

Here's a Working code:

```css
option:checked {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<select name="Occupancy Status" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option selected>Select your Occupany Status</option>
  <option>bla bla</option>
  <option>bla bla</option>
  <option>bla bla</option>
</select>
```

Comment: My desired output is, when dropdown list loads, selected option (`Select your Occupany Status`) background is set to #333333 and background for all remaining option is white. An example of which is given here (https://www.greenhomesystems.co.uk/apply-for-eco4-funding/#eco4-questionnaire). In your working right now, `background` for the selected option is white. Can you please show me that? Thanks

Comment: If you have an example of exactly what you are looking for, why not just use Inspect and copy exactly what they did?

Comment: @StephenMIrving Good point, I tried but failed.  Example link (https://www.greenhomesystems.co.uk/apply-for-eco4-funding/#eco4-questionnaire)

Comment: In your example page, the selected option on the dropdown when the dropdown is closed matches the dark background color because they set the `select` element to have `background-color: transparent`. It doesn't seem to me than anything besides that is what is going on.

Comment: @atch attempted to figure it out what you wanted and posted an answer for you.